# Why can't I change the DB folder for a new Neo4j DB?

Tags: neo4j

I've just downloaded and installed Neo4j Community Edition and wil try to generate my own local DB.

I'm NOT allowed to change the folder - gets the message as below:

```
Please choose a different folder.[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@562b80b3
```

Why and how can I change the folder and create my own DB ?

Comment: I'm running Windows 10 fully updated

Comment: Why is that EDIT so needed - the error message doesn't look like this - it's a 2 line message in a listbox on a windows form ...

Comment: Are you using the EXE installation or the ZIP installation ?

Comment: In the first place I downloaded the ZIP-file, unpacked it and now running the EXE-file in here: "C:\Program Files\Neo4j CE 3.2.5\bin" by a shortcut

Comment: IS this crap working at all ?

Comment: Oh, I got it - the neo4j.BAT with parameter install-service BUT ... (how the Hell do I shift line here ?) error message "Could not locate JVM.DLL ...

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall the Neo4j installation you have now.
2. Download https://neo4j.com/download-thanks/?edition=community&flavour=winzip&release=3.2.5
3. Unpack that zip where you want Neo4j to live.
4. Open a (admin) command shell, cd to your [installation-location]
5. bin\neo4j install-service
6. bin\neo4j start

And you're done and Neo4j is running. Everything lives in the [installation-location]. You can change that by changing things in [installation-location]\neo4j.conf (requires a restart of Neo4j).

It is obvious from your comments that the exe-installation is frustrating you. It is intended to get people started quickly but is not very flexible. Get rid of it and use the above mentioned zip. Not only does it give you more flexibility, it also contains a more complete toolset.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Add 5) ... nothing there called "neo4j install-service" - here is what's there: 
14-06-2017  12:50             2.486 cypher-shell.bat
15-09-2017  21:00             1.022 neo4j-admin.bat
15-09-2017  21:00             1.023 neo4j-import.bat
06-10-2017  15:38    <DIR>          Neo4j-Management
15-09-2017  21:00             1.438 Neo4j-Management.psd1
15-09-2017  21:00             1.022 neo4j-shell.bat
15-09-2017  21:00             1.113 neo4j.bat
06-10-2017  15:38    <DIR>          tools

Comment: That's bin\neo4j.bat install-service ... a command with a parameter ? And it will work without the .bat as well as windows will find the .bat automatically.

Comment: That's NOT the problem - it's as though it assumes another folder structure than is tha case in Windows 10 when referring to this JAVA_HOME

Comment: It's not clear what error you are referring to then, but if you're talking about the missing jvm.dll ... the reason for that is that you have a limited jre installation. You may want to install a full one from the Oracle site.